# Is It possible to get Text value if the structure like this?

Tags: dart, flutter

```
          children: <Widget>[  
       new Text
            (_value,textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),

            new RaisedButton
              (onPressed: (_selectDate),
               child: new Text('Select Date..'),
              ),

      ...
     ]
```

i tried to make Text txt = new Text("something") already to get value from txt.text but it say,

"[dart] The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. [list_element_type_not_assignable]"

Comment: where is the code you try to make assignment?

Answer (score 0):

sorry i already get the answer,

so i try to change it to textfield, bound it with controller, then set the controller value when i call my function _selectDate..

so this is my answer :
TextEditingController ctrlperiode = TextEditingController();

Future _selectDate()  async
   {
    ...

```
ctrlperiode.text =_value   ;
}
```

thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  Text x = Text('123123');
  Text y = Text(x.data);
  print(y.data);
  String val = Text('xxxx').data;
  print(val);
```

However, if the value for `Text` widget is bound to a state variable, you can just initialize it already.

```
 Text newWidgetText = Text(_stateValue);
```